# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'server', Run with Cloud SQL

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, fastapi, google-cloud-sql

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

URL_DATABASE = 'mysql+pymysql://root:12345@34.101.234.148:3306/test'

engine = create_engine(URL_DATABASE)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

i can run it in local but when i deploy it in GCP many error

I change the URL_DATABASE so many times, then i add 0.0.0.0/0 its done with sqlalchemy problem but make some thing like that "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'server'" i just need to run and deploy it on GCP

Comment: You could forget to install some packages/dependencies, no?

Comment: Please post stacktrace of your error to to give more context on the source of the error. Most likely is missing dependency as mentioned above.

Comment: Did you run the code on your desktop or did you run the container under Docker? Test the container locally with Docker and then deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is most likely due to a missing dependency in your `requirements.txt` file for starting your Cloud Run service and not related to the actual database connection code posted above.

Sidenote: I'd recommend using the [Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector#fastapi) for connecting to your instance from a FastAPI application instead of allow-listing `0.0.0.0/0` as that allows your instance to be reachable by any IP address (not secure). [Here is an example of a FastAPI application](https://github.com/jackwotherspoon/cloud-sql-fastapi/tree/main/expense-tracker) that connects to Cloud SQL and is deployed to Cloud Run.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a python error for me. Don't think it is related to the Cloud SQL itself.  Are you sure all the modules are installed on your machine correctly? I am not sure which one of your modules is called 'server'. It is hard to say which one since we have only small piece of the code and have no information about the code deployment process.